# With/Height layout misaligned after CSS rotate on inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

After rotating a group of rectangular `inline-block` elements, the new width and height are not respected in the layout flow. This means that they are left overlapping one-another. Is there any way around this with CSS?

In the example below, note how the left margins are covered and there is a large white space above second line of blocks.

```css
p {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
}
.r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
Before:
<br/>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<hr/>After:
<br/>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKqjoR?editors=1100#0

[image]

Comment: My answer gives you exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page layout is always processed by the browser *before* CSS transforms are applied, and there is currently no way to trigger CSS to re-process the layout afterwards. Therefore, the only way around this issue is to add extra margins to the rotated elements to manually reposition them.

**A general-use formula for repositioning rotated elements is as follows:**

```
M = absoluteValueOf( [element height] - [element width] )/2

margin: -M-[margin-top]/2, M+[margin-left]/2;
```

**In the example above, this would be:**

```
M = (80 - 20)/2                       = 30

margin: -30-0/2, 30+10/2              = -30 35
```

**The final CSS:**

```
.r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin:-30px 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left: 75px` will give them even spacing.

```css
p {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
}
.r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
Before:
<br/>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<hr/>After:
<br/>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`transform` does not *actually* affect layout and positioning...it's an entirely *visual* effect.

Height does not become width and vice versa.

You'd need to adjust the margins accordingly...something like this:

```css
p {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
}
p.r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
Before:
<br/>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<hr/>After:
<br/>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
}
.r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:40px;
}
```

```html
Before:<br/>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<hr/>After:<br/>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
<p class='r'></p>
```

```
Use Following code: 

<pre>
.r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:40px;
}
</pre>

Note:
I have added margin left and margin right because the height provided by you is 80px and 
when it is rotating all are overlapping with each other because previous width was 20px 
and after rotating now width is 80px (after rotate height converted in width).
```